# event.preventDefault() not working (jQuery live)

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

EDIT:

**The goal is to NOT have the screen move to the top of the page when clicking the link. I just want it to hide the short description and show the full one.**

```
jQuery("#more_info a").live('click', function(event)
{
    event.preventDefault();
    jQuery('#food_desc').hide();
    jQuery('#food_desc_full').show();
});
```

The above code works except for stopping the default event (going to the top of the page) from happening. Is it because of the live() event?

EDIT:

I even tried this:

```
if (data.body_summary)
{
    jQuery("#food_desc").append('<p id="more_info"><a href="#">MORE &raquo;</a></p>');
    jQuery("#more_info a").click(function(event)
    {
        event.preventDefault();
        jQuery('#food_desc').hide();
        jQuery('#food_desc_full').show();
        return false;
    });

}
```

Still goes to top of page...

I also tried this:

```
jQuery("body").delegate("#more_info a", "click", function(event) 
{
    event.stopPropagation();
    event.preventDefault();
    jQuery('#food_desc').hide();
    jQuery('#food_desc_full').show();
    return false;
});
```

It does the show/hide of long/short description but doesn't stop the page from going to top.

Comment: Yes, because `live` binds the event to the document. Are you aware that it's [deprecated](http://liveisdeprecated.com)?

Comment: Yes I am aware it is deprecated. What are the alternatives?

Comment: When the event handler is executed, the event already bubbled to the top. But `preventDefault` does not stop the event propagation anyway, `stopPropagation` does. It won't help either though... you have to bind the event handler to an element that is between `#more_info a` and `#food_desc` if you want to prevent it reach those elements.

Comment: @ChrisMuench - Event delegation with [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) (jQuery 1.7+) or [`.delegate()`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/).

Comment: `return false;` works perfectly: http://jsfiddle.net/S8QPX/. We could help you more if you explain what you are actually trying to do and provide an example of your markup.

Comment: just FYI since you are dynamically adding those elements.  ID's must be unique.  Unless you are only adding it once it would be a good idea to append a number or something after the ID

Answer (score 0):

From the [docs](http://api.jquery.com/live/):

> Calling `event.stopPropagation()` in the event handler is ineffective in
>   stopping event handlers attached lower in the document; the event has
>   already propagated to document.

You should use [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) instead, or [`.delegate()`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) if you don't yet use 1.7+.

Answer (score 0):

Isn't this because of the `#` in the `href`?

Answer (score 0):

You me need return false in the onclick event of the tag. Check out this SO question [event.preventDefault() vs. return false](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1357118/event-preventdefault-vs-return-false)

Comment: I tried adding onclick="return false;" to the markup and that doesn't work either. I never remember having so much trouble getting the default action NOT to fire.

Answer (score 0):

you need to do `return false;` in delegate for live both you `e.stopPropagation();` useless